# How do you append text and a button to a list item with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, list, button, listitem

I'm trying to make a pretty simple to-do list.  You type in something, it gets added to the list and stored in the local storage.  My next step is adding a button next to each list item that I could then use to individually delete things as opposed to deleting the whole list.  I've found a couple of SO questions about making buttons with jQuery and tried to follow them, but something isn't working right because I'm not getting the right output.  Here's the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <!--Project-->
    <html>
        <head>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    let list = [];
                    if (localStorage.getItem("mylist") != null) {
                        let array = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("mylist"));
                        for (let element of array) {
                            list.push(element);
                            $('#list').append('<li>' + element + '</li>');
                        }
                    }
                    $('button').click(function() {
                        if ((this.id) == "add") {
                            let input = $('#input').val();
                          
                            // making button?
                            let button = $('<button/>', {type:'button', id:input, text:'Delete'});
                            
                            // appending text and button?
                            $('#list').append('<li>' + input + button + '</li>');
                          
                            list.push(input);
                            let json = JSON.stringify(list);
                            localStorage.setItem("mylist", json);
                            $('#input').val('');
                        }
                        else {
                            localStorage.clear();
                            $("#list").empty();
                        }
                        event.preventDefault();
                    });
                });
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <form>
                <input type="text" id="input" placeholder="Enter tasks...">
                <button id="add">Add</button>
                <button id="delete">Delete All</button>
                <br>
                <ul id="list">
                </ul>
              
            </form>
        </body>
    </html>
```

For some reason, I'm just getting the text from the input box and [object Object] next to that.  I'm not really sure what to do as I'm having trouble finding documentation on how to create elements in this way using jQuery.  I'm trying to create a button that has an ID that matches the text that was put into the text box, that way I can later reference that ID and use it to delete stuff.  Maybe there's another way I should be going about this?  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting `[object Object]` next to that, because you are concatenating a OBJECT, and not a string (or a string with the html code of your button, as expected).

```
// Here you are actually creating correctly the button
// making button?
let button = $('<button/>', {type:'button', id:input, text:'Delete'});

// BUT HERE you're passing the button concatenated with the string `input`. That won't work.
// appending text and button?
$('#list').append('<li>' + input + button + '</li>');
```

That's equivalent to the following:

```
$('#list').append('<li>' + 'any text' + $('<button>') + '</li>');
```

As you can see, you are NOT concatenating the html code of your new button, but instead you are concatenating a DOM element (actually a jQuery object, but still...). When you try to concatenate a a `string` with a `object`, javascript tries to convert the `object` to a string that represents that object. The result of this conversion on this case is `'[object Object]'`.

**Solution:**

*Just change the `button` that is the object, to its html code. You can simply do that with `outerHTML` property of DOM Elements. Since your `button` object is a jQuery object, and jQuery objects are treated as collections, you need to get the first object in this collection with `[0]`, and only then call the `outerHTML` property, since it only works (at least as expected) with standard javascript objects.*

```
// appending text and button?
$('#list').append('<li>' + input + button[0].outerHTML + '</li>');
```

Comment: Awesome!  I knew it was something stupid like that.  Thank you so much.  Can you tell me why you needed to do `button[0].outerHTML` instead of just `button.outerHTML`?

Comment: @dylosaur added the explanation in edit. Please, let me know if it's clear to you. If it isn't, i'll try to explain in a even more detailed way.

Comment: @dylosaur You're more than welcome. Really glad I could help!